# Proof $P \left(\frac{ |X_{1}+...+X_{n}|}{n} > \epsilon \right) \rightarrow 0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let be  $X_{1},X_{2},...$ a sequence of independen random variables with $E(x_i)=0$ and $Var(x_i)=\sigma^{2}$, also $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum _{i=1}^{n} \frac{\sigma_{i}^{2}}{n^2} = 0$.

Proof that $ \forall \epsilon  \ $ $ P \left(\frac{ |X_{1}+...+X_{n}|}{n} > \epsilon \right)  \rightarrow 0$

My answere is:

Let be $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}  \implies E(Y)=nE(X_i)=n*0=0 ;   \ Var(Y)=nVar(X_i)=n*\sigma_{i}^{2}  $

With the chebyshev´s inequality we have:

$P(|Y-0| \geq \epsilon ) \leq \frac{n \sigma_{i}^2}{\epsilon^{2}}$ , let be $\epsilon=n \epsilon$

$P\left( \frac{|Y|}{n} \geq \epsilon \right) \leq  \frac{1}{n} \frac{\sigma_{i}^{2}}{\epsilon^2}$

If we take limit, $\lim_{n \to \infty }  \frac{1}{n} = 0$

$\implies \ P \left(\frac{ |X_{1}+...+X_{n}|}{n} > \epsilon \right)  \rightarrow 0 $

But I don't know what's up with the summation hypothesis.

I need to use this result to proof if $X_{i} \sim Ber(p_{i})$ then for $ \forall \epsilon P\left( 
| \frac{X_1+...+X_{n}}{n} - p(n) |  \leq \epsilon \right) \to 1$ when $n \to \infty$ and $p(n)= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i }{n}$

Comment: You've done all the work. Just observe that $\mathbb{E} X_i=p_i$ and apply the result to $Y_i=X_i-p_i$.

Comment: Why should the variance of $Y$ include both the variances of each $X_i$ *and* a multiplication by $n$?

Comment: Because $X_{i}, X_{j}$ are independent and the variance is the sum of the variances, I think so.

Answer (score 2):

With $Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ you have $\text{Var}(Y_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i^2$, where $\sigma_i^2=\text{Var}(X_i)$. Now, as you correctly say, we use Chebyshev's inequality:
$$
P(\frac{|Y_n|}{n}>\epsilon)\leq\frac{\text{Var}(Y_n/n)}{\epsilon^2}=\epsilon^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sigma_i^2}{n^2}.
$$
The right-hand side converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ due to the summation hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

With the hint of @Alan I think that the answere is:

Let be $Y_{i}=X_{i}-p_{i}\ $ then $ \ E(Y_{i})=E(X_{i})-p_{i}=p_i - p_i = 0$

Then $Var(Y_i)=\sigma_{i}^{2}$

We have for the property $P\left( \frac{|Y_1+...+Y_n|}{n}  > \epsilon \right) \to 0$

$\implies P\left( \frac{|X_1+...+X_n - (p_1 + ... + p_n)|}{n}  > \epsilon \right) \to 0 $ also we have that $n>0 \implies |n|=n$
$\implies P\left( |\frac{X_1+...+X_n - (p_1 + ... + p_n)}{n}|  > \epsilon \right) \to 0 $

Finally we get complement:

$\implies P\left( |\frac{X_1+...+X_n }{n} - p(n)|  \geq  \epsilon \right) \to 1 $